# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglut

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm getting the following error while trying to install mp4box and running the make lib command.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglut
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libgpac.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/gpac/src'
make: *** [lib] Error 2
```

After I check the libraries that's what I get:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      13 Feb 15 18:25 libGL.so -> mesa/libGL.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  905952 Aug 23  2011 libGLU.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      11 Feb 15 18:26 libGLU.so -> libGLU.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      20 Feb 15 18:25 libGLU.so.1 -> libGLU.so.1.3.071000
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  453272 Aug 23  2011 libGLU.so.1.3.071000
baseem@348588:/usr/lib$ ln -s libGLU.so.1.3.071000 libGL.so
ln: creating symbolic link `libGL.so': File exists
```

Note: I'm a total newb in linux so please take that into consideration!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 30):

You're going to need an implementation of GLUT. The easiest one to get is FreeGLUT:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev
```

Comment: I got this error when I tried it:
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-2.6.38-16-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-image

Comment: ...? Do you usually use `apt-get` at all?

Answer (score 0):

I was running on the same problem when i was trying to install MP4Box then i found the solution.

first of all check to see if your configuration file produce any errors. for example (permission denied error) :
in this case you need to change the TMPDIR1 line in your configure file (line 7 before fi) to the following:

```
    TMPDIR1=/usr/local/src
```

then you need to install glut using this command :

```
    yum install  glut-devel
```

now if you run the following command

```
    ls /usr/lib64 |grep glut
```

you will se that you have libglut.so (if you cant libglut.so@ you need to create symbolic link to it)
then everything should work properly