# Missing recommended library: libGLU.so

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cuda, gpu

I am trying to install [NVIDIA CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). When it is installing the tool kit, it displayed the following error message.

```
Missing recommended library: libGLU.so
Missing recommended library: libXi.so
Missing recommended library: libXmu.so
```

I am not a Linux guy, so I used `apt-get install libGLU.so` to install it, but it did not work. How can I fix this and install these? I am on 32 bit Linux.

Comment: For the close voters: If "any" of you is a hero to install the libGLU, then tell it first.

Comment: Possibly accept my answer if it worked for you? :)

Answer (score 23):

Try `apt-get install libglu1-mesa libxi-dev libxmu-dev libglu1-mesa-dev`. You can find this info yourself by [searching the Ubuntu package contents](http://packages.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. libGLU is still missing, others are installed,

Comment: It's possible that the `libglu1-mesa` install did not set up a necessary symbolic link.  Something like this may be needed: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1 /usr/lib/libGLU.so`  HOWEVER, the directories may be sligltly different, such as `/usr/lib32` instead of `/usr/lib`.  So learn what a symbolic link is (`man ln`), then poke around and see if you can find where `libglu1-mesa` put the `libGLU.so.1` file, then use that path accordingly.

Comment: I checked in both /usr/lib and /usr/lib32. Could not find it.

Comment: are there any libGLU.so.xxxxxxx files anywhere on your system?  It may require two symbolic links  libGLU.so -> libGLU.so.1 -> libGLU.so.11.5.19 or something like that.  Learn how to search for files in linux.  You can start with `sudo ls -l -R /* |grep libGLU`

Comment: @RobertCrovella I'd suggest `find / -name 'libGLU*'` instead.

Comment: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 /usr/lib/libGLU.so` on Ubuntu 14.04 did the job. Moreover, I did the `sudo ldconfig` after that.

Comment: @Tracer try installing this     sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev

Answer (score 7):

I use nvidia-docker to setup a CUDA develop environment, also encounter the same issue. So I try to solve this issue and writing down a Dockerfile. Also adding some useful comments, hope it'll be helpful.

Here is my Dockerfile:

https://github.com/allenyllee/server_setup/blob/master/nvidia_docker/Dockerfile

```
# CUDA 8.0
#
# VERSION               0.0.1

FROM      nvidia/cuda:8.0-devel-ubuntu16.04
LABEL     maintainer="allen7575@gmail.com"

##
## Ubuntu - Packages - Search
## https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&section=all&arch=amd64&searchon=contents&keywords=Search
##

###
### solve for
### >>> WARNING - libGL.so not found, refer to CUDA Getting Started Guide for how to find and install them. <<<
### >>> WARNING - libX11.so not found, refer to CUDA Getting Started Guide for how to find and install them. <<<
### >>> WARNING - Xlib.h not found, refer to CUDA Getting Started Guide for how to find and install them. <<<
### >>> WARNING - gl.h not found, refer to CUDA Getting Started Guide for how to find and install them. <<<
###
### 2_Graphics/volumeFiltering
### 2_Graphics/simpleGL
### 2_Graphics/bindlessTexture
### 2_Graphics/volumeRender
### 2_Graphics/Mandelbrot
### 2_Graphics/marchingCubes
### 2_Graphics/simpleTexture3D
### 3_Imaging/imageDenoising
### 3_Imaging/recursiveGaussian
### 3_Imaging/simpleCUDA2GL
### 3_Imaging/postProcessGL
### 3_Imaging/bicubicTexture
### 3_Imaging/boxFilter
### 3_Imaging/SobelFilter
### 3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL
### 3_Imaging/bilateralFilter
### 5_Simulations/particles
### 5_Simulations/smokeParticles
### 5_Simulations/oceanFFT
### 5_Simulations/fluidsGL
### 5_Simulations/nbody
### 6_Advanced/FunctionPointers
### 7_CUDALibraries/randomFog
###
RUN apt update && apt -y install libgl1-mesa-dev

###
### solve for
### >>> WARNING - libGLU.so not found, refer to CUDA Getting Started Guide for how to find and install them. <<<
### >>> WARNING - glu.h not found, refer to CUDA Getting Started Guide for how to find and install them. <<<
### 
RUN apt update && apt -y install libglu1-mesa-dev

###
### solve for
### /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglut
### https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064159/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lglut
###
RUN apt update && apt -y install freeglut3-dev

### 
### solve for
### >>> WARNING - egl.h not found, please install egl.h <<<
### >>> WARNING - eglext.h not found, please install eglext.h <<<
### >>> WARNING - gl31.h not found, please install gl31.h <<<
###
### 2_Graphics/simpleGLES_EGLOutput
### 2_Graphics/simpleGLES
### 2_Graphics/simpleGLES_screen
### 5_Simulations/nbody_opengles
### 5_Simulations/fluidsGLES
### 5_Simulations/nbody_screen
###
RUN apt update && apt -y install libgles2-mesa-dev


###
### You should also search 'UBUNTU_PKG_NAME = "nvidia-367"' and replace it to 'UBUNTU_PKG_NAME = "nvidia"' 
### for all matched files in the NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples folder to make it works.
###
RUN mkdir /usr/lib/nvidia && \
    ### solve for  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnvcuvid \
    ### 3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL \
    ln -s /usr/local/nvidia/lib64/libnvcuvid.so.1 /usr/lib/nvidia/libnvcuvid.so && \
    ### solve for >>> WARNING - libEGL.so not found, please install libEGL.so <<< \
    ### 3_Imaging/EGLStreams_CUDA_Interop \
    ln -s /usr/local/nvidia/lib64/libEGL.so.1 /usr/lib/nvidia/libEGL.so && \
    ### solve for >>> WARNING - libGLES.so not found, please install libGLES.so <<< \
    ### 2_Graphics/simpleGLES_EGLOutput \
    ### 2_Graphics/simpleGLES \
    ### 2_Graphics/simpleGLES_screen \
    ### 5_Simulations/nbody_opengles \
    ### 5_Simulations/fluidsGLES \
    ### 5_Simulations/nbody_screen \
    ln -s /usr/local/nvidia/lib64/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2 /usr/lib/nvidia/libGLESv2.so


CMD    ["bash"]
```

Answer (score 3):

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42428296/3425200 ,
After you installed the libs, you should set the environment to make:

```
GLPATH=/usr/lib make
```

instead of make.

Answer (score 3):

may be helpful for other user use yum:
work for me in cuda-10.0:

> sudo yum install mesa-libGLU-devel mesa-libGL-devel  libXmu-devel.i686
>   libXi-devel.i686

Answer (score 0):

After you do the installation of the above 3rd party libraries, no harm running the NVIDIA driver installation again if you encounter something like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../libGL.so when searching for -lGL/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libGL.so when searching for -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libGL.so when searching for -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [simpleGL] Error 1
```

This is because some of the symbolic links were broken by the installation. This is CUDA 7 with CentOS 7. 
https://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=migr-5094265

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I tried `sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa` and it worked.